# Replacing some text in Notepad++ with different words in a predefind list

Tags: notepad++

I need to replace same text in notepad++ with different words.
For example

```
hello user
hello user
hello user
hello user
```

I need to replace "user" with Alex, Moody, Tom, Meena, Himangi etc. Some hundreds are there, How can it be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simple:

Firstly I have to assume that you have somehow a list with all your names. For example, I will assume that they are saved as a space-comma delimited list in a txt file. (if this isn't the case and you can't understand how to adapt the example to your data, let me know how your names are stored and I'll adapt the answer)

> Alex, Moody, Tom, Meena, Himangi, ...

Then go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z]+)(?:, )?
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   Hello $1\n
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press "Replace All"

This will give you:

```
Hello Alex
Hello Moody
Hello Tom
Hello Meena
Hello Himangi
...
```

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jC8gV1).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least, not without a plugin. And I'm not aware of a plugin for that.

You can accomplish this in Python rather easily though.

```
import re

text = """
hello user
hello user
hello user"""

names = [ "name1", "name2", "name3" ]

for name in names:
    text = re.sub("user", name, text, count=1)
```

Also, for the record, I think there is a better way to write this code, but I can't think of it while I'm at work. :P